# Why does input of my training dataset creates *Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float)* error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

> I am getting the error 'Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).'
> on the input of my **label** to tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( ) function. However when i pop >**label** from **training_df** and input **dict(training_df)** in the function the error gets resolved.

> Kindly help.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
 
from tensorflow import feature_column
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#tf.enable_eager_execution()

training_df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\ML\\train.csv')

train , test = train_test_split(training_df,test_size=0.2)
train , val = train_test_split(train,test_size=0.25)

print(type(train))

   
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)

label = train.pop('Survived') #survived is my label
         
train_ds = (
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (
           dict(train),
           label
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you link the CSV file so the error can be reproduced? Also, can you remove all the useless code? Seems like all the feature_column part is unrelated

Comment: Check the array that you are trying to convert.  Looks like it's `object` dtype.  What's the `shape`?  If that is 1d, it's likely you've created the array from arrays or images that vary in shape.  It's not a multidimensional array that can be turned into a tensor.

Comment: @NicolasGervais i cleaned the code. i downloaded the datasets from kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

Comment: @hpaulj i import a csv file into a dataframe which is `training_df `. Now i split that dataframe into three dataframes which are `train, test and val`.  My question was why tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices works only when i pass the `training_df` as dict and not `train` dataframe.

Comment: The issue got resolved once i matched the shapes of all dataframes. Thanks for help @hpaulj